# server send push notification to client browser without using polling

Tags: browser, push-notification, server-push

I am developing a web app in which I want that when some changes in database occurs, server sends response to particular client(***like push notification***). And I want this notification to be sent client's browser. I don't want to use polling.

What can I do?
I think it's possible using [**SSE**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/), but I am not clear.
I want to know

- Is it possible to send response to particular client without client's request(without polling).
- How server will detect that particular client?

please help me.

Comment: As you've said, SSE seems to be the way to go. What, more precisely, is not clear on the HTML5 example you link to? Also consider this 2013 Sinatra example: http://html5hacks.com/blog/2013/04/21/push-notifications-to-the-browser-with-server-sent-events/ and current proposed W3C recommendation: http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there some way to PUSH data from web server to browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995/is-there-some-way-to-push-data-from-web-server-to-browser)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Web Notification](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/). And [there](http://caniuse.com/notifications) you can see the browsers that support it.

Comment: hey u know what i want actualy..? I want that types of news updates like facebook gives at the top-right side of the page.. Any idea how to do this without using polling..?

Comment: Well if you have a webserver and you want the notifications to come through while the app/site is running in your browser then you can use WebSocket. WebSocket does not require polling. So, when there is data available or, a change that you want to communicate to the connected browsers you can then push them. Do you know about WebSockets?

Comment: yaaa.. i know websockets but i want to know which is best option in my case websockets or SSE..?

Comment: It is hard to tell as your case it quite limited. If it is only about receiving notifications then both are equally valid in my opinion. I do not know much about the server side implementation for SSE but for web-socket it is quite easy even if you are building things from scratch. Also, if your case evolves then you should consider constraints such as, SSE is uni-directional while with web-sockets it is bi-directional. So, it depends as you can see.

Comment: No worries. Somehow i feel i did not do much to help :)

Comment: Mmmm, isn't Web Notifications for showing a popup outside of the browser? Can you give a working example of server to browser data push?