# HTML push data from server to client updates without polling

Tags: php, javascript, html, ios, push

I'm needing to write a web page that is displayed on a mobile device but the tricky part is that the content needs to be a live updateable feed... think instant messenger or chatroom style updates.

I've taken a quick look at SSE and seems firstly this is tricky to do correctly in PHP with multiple connections occurring.  Secondly I'm not even sure if the webview's in iOS/Android/BB will even support this feature since I haven't found a tutorial that actually works yet.

[SSE basics tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

[Reading this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352341/server-send-push-notification-to-client-browser-without-using-polling) it seems like websockets are the way forward but anyone have any experience in using these with iOS/Android?

Ideally I need it so that an update on the server appears on the mobile devices/laptops within 5 seconds (instantly would be incredible but I expect unrealistic)

*A few methods considered and ruled out.*

- HW Push notifications to the native app to flag an update is available isn't feasible as it has to work for devices that don't have this feature.
- Short polling is probably not feasible due to bandwidth restrictions that thousands may be using it at the same time.

Any and all ideas really welcome as I can't believe this is a rare request??

Comment: Have you looked into using Node.js? It is much more suitable for creating multiple persistent connections.

Comment: I second that, socket.io + node.js are quite easy to use.

Comment: I've heard about it but was comfortable with PHP, is NodeJS that much better than PHP for this sort of thing?

Comment: it will take a bit to get started