# Best way to update an out value in asp.net (DataBase & Label)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

Please take a look the link below :
https://www.cryptocompare.com/
As you see **BTC - USD** price is updating every some seconds in that web site.
I want to do same job on my web site with two points :

1. Update price label in every some seconds & show it to user.
2. In every update of price label save the new price to my database.

Imagine i have 1000 users.
So what is the best method to do this job and how can do that?
How can i create a relation between **server side** (save to database) & **client side** (update label)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems similar to this one:

[Is there some way to PUSH data from web server to browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995/is-there-some-way-to-push-data-from-web-server-to-browser)

The answers in there give good insight on **Comet / Reverse Ajax** to do what you need.